# rspec-mocks strange behaviour

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I am encountering strange behaviour with mocks in rspec, I am m getting "'stub' NoMethodError", but when I import using require 'rspec/mocks/standalone' everything works fine. But it seems strange to me.

**My spec_helper:**

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/mocks'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require File.expand_path('../../lib/rwebcli.rb', __FILE__)


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_framework = :rspec

  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true

  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  config.filter_run :focus

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = 'random'

end
```

Comment: can you post a spec that breaks (ie a use case of `stub` with it's surroundings)?

Comment: https://github.com/strangeworks/rwebcli/blob/master/spec/basic_interface_spec.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within the describe block you need an `it`section to be able to use `stub`

```
describe 'foo' do
  it 'should do something' do
    Bar.stub(:meh).and_return(true)
    Bar.meh.should be_true
  end
end
```

I debugged the same problem for a day a while back.